# c++ error when compiling from terminal on mac

Tags: c++, macos, terminal

Trying to compile my program called main.cpp using the 
`gcc main.cpp` 
command to compile on my mac using terminal. I get the following error

```
undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      _main in main-db0d6c.o
. . . 
Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in main-db0d6c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

here is the program:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string name;
   std::cout << "What is your name? ";
   getline (std::cin, name);
   std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, even pointing me in the right direction. I don't understand how to read this error message and would like to learn as well as get my basic program running.

Comment: Could you show the command you're using to compile this?

Comment: use g++ **not** gcc.

Comment: @InternetAussie, the OP did by saying *called main.cpp using gcc main.cpp*

Comment: *facepalm* I missed that

Answer (score 0):

Use g++ not gcc for c++ projects. Also, add `std` to `getline` as `std::getline`